# How to see detailed log of nVidia driver crash on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, crash

While doing GPU-intensive parallel processing, nVidia driver apparently crashed. Only information in Windows Event log is the following:

> The description for Event ID 1 from source NVIDIA OpenGL Driver cannot
>   be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed
>   on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can
>   install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Unable to communicate with the display driver.  The application must
>   close.
>
> Error code: 2
>
> Source: NVIDIA OpenGL driver

I checked and we have the latest NVIDIA driver installed.

I would like to investigate and/or report the problem to NVIDIA, but this information is clearly not enough for reporting. Is there a place where I can see what could have been the source of the problem? I.e., the error in Windows Event log only shows me that communicating with the driver failed, but it does not give information why the crash happened.

Also, if it is not possible to find the reason of the crash, then I would like to at least know how to increase diagnostics/logging for the future so I can trace the problem if it re-occurs.

PS. 4 processes were doing a similar GPU-intensive task at the same time, and each of them received the same error.
PPS. I was not at the computer at the time of the crash. When I came to work at the morning, the screen was completely blank (but the computer was running). Only after restart did everything go back to normal.
PPPS. Graphics card was working normally up to that point.

System I am running is:
Windows 10

Graphics card:
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Graphics card driver version:
10.18.13.6822

Graphics card driver date:
2016-05-19

(I assume that the nVidia OpenGL driver version = nVidia driver version. If that is not so, please let me know where I can check the nVidia OpenGL driver version).